# Get ReadTimeout using webdrivers selenium on Heroku

Tags: selenium-webdriver, heroku, rspec, capybara, webdrivers-gem

I get the following error when using selenium webdrivers on heroku. (rspec->capybara->selenium)

```rb
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>
```

I have the `heroku-buildpack-google-chrome` buildpack, with webdrivers-gem.

And have the following block in spec setup:

```rb
chrome_shim = ENV.fetch("GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM", nil)

Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = chrome_shim

chrome_opts = { "chromeOptions" => { "binary" => chrome_shim } }

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app,
      browser: :chrome,
      desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chrome_opts)
    )
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

`Webdrivers.logger.level = :DEBUG` output is here https://gist.github.com/IanVaughan/3e0c50d2fa4a60e672b96f6726fbbb8c

```
capybara (3.30.0)
webdrivers (4.2.0)
selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
```

Full stack trace: https://gist.github.com/IanVaughan/09b31613833d965ee4f3b7d1e48fd1e2

The spec I'm running is :

```rb
RSpec.feature 'User signup flow', :js do
  scenario 'Visits home page to signup' do
    visit root_path
    new_window = window_opened_by { click_link 'Sign Up', match: :first }
    within_window new_window do
      expect(page).to have_text('New Enquiry', wait: 5)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Put the actual versions of gems used - putting the limits (capybara >=2.15) doesn't actually tell us what versions you're using (also put the selenium-webdriver version). Also when do you get that error? Show the stacktrace.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thanks for pointing that out, good point, I've added the gem versions as requested. And added full stack trace. Cheers

Comment: From the stacktrace selenium is hanging trying to get window handles - which would imply a chromedriver/chrome issue - can you show your whole test scenario  just to confirm nothing strange is being done?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I've added the spec!

Comment: Sounds like a chromedriver bug - check the chromedriver  projects issues

Answer (score 3):

If the timeout is happening during your apps first request, while the apps doing something onetime (compiling assets, etc), then you may need to increase the allowed read timeout

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      ...
      timeout: 60 # defaults to 30 IIRC
    )
end
```

Comment: Good idea, it's odd though because locally the test runs within 3 seconds. And when run on Heroku it waits for ages anyway, around a minute, and then fails. I tried this timeout setting and it didnt help, cheers

Comment: We're getting the same problem @IanVaughan, did you get this resolved? Did you try Kiran's suggestion above? Super annoying, it's only intermittent for us though.

Answer (score -1):

It could be possibly the cookies are cleared after 30 sec in headless mode

Add this in chrome options and try if its works:)

```
--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess
```